# How to Test a IPhone Project?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

im new to iPhone. Can any one tell the iphone unit step step by step procedure. i tried [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW1).but i have some errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[FileManager setLatitude:andLongitude:] in FileApiManager.o
```

I hope i made some mistakes on my previous steps. can any one tell me a handy way or step wise procedure from how to configure the test project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems your issue comes from a library. Have you add the CoreLocation and the CLLocation framework to your project?

Answer (score 1):

It looks likes you're missing a library reference, though from the error message I couldn't tell you which one. Are you using any custom libraries for your testing/development? Did you included them correctly?

Project Overview -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries is where you can go to check on that. Double check and make sure that CLLocation and CoreLocation are included as Yannick suggested.